Laravel Echo Pusher [message":"Auth info required to subscribe to private-App.Models.PharmacyUser.1"]
I'm using Laravel and Pusher to create an api for a mobile app, using broadcasting with pusher:
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Broadcast::routes(["prefix" => "api", "middleware" => ["auth:sanctum"]]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}

Broadcasting file:
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

Channel:
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.PharmacyUser.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return true;
});

And here's my mobile client using Laravel Echo and pusher js react native:
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import axios from 'axios';

export default new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    Pusher, // sets the instance imported above
    key: '************', // set the key defined in your .env
    forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true,
    cluster: 'us2',
    authorizer: (channel, options) => {
        return {
            authorize: async (socketId, callback) => {
                let pharmacyToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('pharmacy-token');
                console.log('pharmacyToken', pharmacyToken);
                try {
                    const response = await axios.post(
                        'https://api.*********.com/broadcasting/auth',
                        {
                            socket_id: socketId,
                            channel_name: channel.name,
                        },
                        {
                            headers: {
                                Authorization: `Bearer ${pharmacyToken}`,
                                'X-APP-NAME': 'mobile',
                                Accept: 'application/json',
                            },
                        },
                    );

                    console.log('response', response.data);
                    callback(false, response.data);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('WS error', error);
                    callback(true, error);
                }
            },
        };
    },
});

However ,no matter what I've tried, I always get:
Pusher :  : [{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth info required to subscribe to private-App.Models.PharmacyUser.1"}}]

Even tho I'm sending the correct bearer token, I'm trying to authenticate it for private channels

have anything in php artisan channel:list? can you put function (User $user, int $id)  and see if  are more errors?  put in middleware just api. check this for more infos.

I assume the key, secret and app_id are set in you .env file?

They are, pretty much did everything to debug, wether by checking the user, etc.

There's a lot of debugging left to be done here. Where are you getting this error message? It doesn't appear to correspond with your console.log() statements. Where are your keys set? Have you cleared your config cache and restarted the listener after changing env files, and confirmed changes have taken effect? Are the correct credentials being sent with the request?
